# Python regular expression question mark operator not working?

Tags: python, regex, capture, option-type

```
import re
str='abc defg'
m1 = re.match(".*(def)?",str)
m2 = re.match(".*(def)",str)
print (m1.group(1),m2.group(1))
```

The output of the above is:

> (None, 'def')

What is going on? Even with a non-greedy repetition operator, the optional capture group `(def)?` is not matched.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what happens when the regex engine tries to match `.*(def)` against `abc defg`:

- First, the engine starts trying to match the regex at the beginning of the string.
- The greedy subpattern `.*` initially tries to match as many times as it can, matching the entire string.
- Since this causes the rest of the match to fail, the regex engine backtracks until it finds a way to match the `(def)`, which happens when the `.*` matches only `abc` .

However, if we change the regex to `.*(def)?`, the following happens instead:

- First, the regex engine again starts at the beginning of the string.
- Next, it again tries to match `.*` as many times as possible, matching the entire string.
- But at that point, since all the rest of the regex is optional, it has found a match for the entire regex!  Since `(def)?` is greedy, the engine *would* prefer to match it if it could, but it's not going to backtrack earlier subpatterns just to see if it can.  Instead, it just lets the `.*` gobble up the entire string, leaving nothing for `(def)?`.

Something similar happens with `.*?(def)` and `.*?(def)?`:

- Again, the engine starts at the beginning of the string.
- The ungreedy subpattern `.*?` tries to match as *few* times as it can, i.e. not at all.
- At that point, `(def)` cannot match, but `(def)?` can.  Thus, for `(def)` the regex engine has to go back and consider longer matches for `.*?` until it finds one that lets the full pattern match, whereas for `(def)?` it doesn't have to do that, and so it doesn't.

For more information, see the ["Combining RE Pieces" section of the Perl regular expressions manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Combining-RE-Pieces) (which matches the behavior of Python's "Perl-compatible" regular expressions).

Comment: I am sorry that I did not accept your answer until now. I was new to the forum and was unsure about things. And thank you for your comprehensive explanation. I have actually written a regex engine before, so I should have been able to figure this out.